# Retrieve field group (tab) label name in ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm running Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress. In ACF, you can group items in Tabs, making it easier to navigate to create a post/page content.

I'm wanting to retrieve the name of the tab, and it's content, programmatically.

Is it possible? I can't find any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you got an answer for your question,

There is no way through php code to get field/subfield data as there is no relationship between tabs and fields under them.

ACF Tabs are only for admin layout to organise fields(hide/show etc) and is done completely through JS/CSS. If you have ACF PRO check the functions in this folder - plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/assets/js/acf-input.js which explains how tabs work in ACF

If you want to get fields which are not in repeater/flexible layouts in an array then, You can get an entire set of fields data, which is explained in this [ACF GET FIELDS IN A GROUP](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/getting-tab-field-names/)

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with this problem today, figured I'd post my solution. Based on my research, there's no way to access the tab field directly except to find it in the field group and iterate backwards until a field of type tab is found.

```php
Class ACFHelper {
    /**
    *  get_field_group_by_name: gets the first matching field group for a given title
    *
    *  @param $title the title of the acf field group
    *  @return Array the fields of the field group or false if not found
    *
    */
    public static function get_field_group_by_name($title) {
        $field_group_post = get_posts([
            'numberposts'   => 1,
            'post_type'     => 'acf-field-group',
            's'             => $title
        ]);

        return ( !empty($field_group_post[0]) ? acf_get_fields( $field_group_post[0]->ID ):false );
    }

    /**
    *  get_tab_by_field_name: gets the tab of a specified field by iterating backwards through the field group
    *
    *  @param $field_group_title the title of the acf field group
    *  @param $field_name the name of the field for which we want the tab it's under
    *  @return Array the field group of the tab or false if not found
    *
    */
    public static function get_tab_by_field_name($field_group_title, $field_name) {
        $field_group = Self::get_field_group_by_name($field_group_title);

        if($field_group) {
            $field_index = array_search($field_name, array_column($field_group, 'name'));

            if($field_index) {
                for($field_index; $field_index > -1; $field_index--) {
                    if( $field_group[$field_index]['type'] == 'tab' )
                        return $field_group[$field_index];
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

So now if I have a field strawberry under the fruits tab, I can find my fruits tab in my foods field group like:

```php
$tab = ACFHelper::get_tab_by_field('foods', 'strawberry');
```